# Security patch 5344 unknown after changing admin url

Tags: patches, reports, supee-5344

The status of my Security patch 5344 (Shoplift) is unknown on MageReport.com after changing Magento admin url. Is this normal or should I change it back?

Answer (score 2):

Is possible that you need to perform other checks, for instance:

> If a check comes up grey it’s possible the files that are needed for the check are relocated. Therefore it can’t see whether your shop is patched or not. No worries. Simply use SSH to check if your shop is patched.
>
> Every check that’s been installed can easily be found in the content of your shop. More specifically it’s logged in app/etc/applied.patches.list . So you use the command ‘grep’ to access the list:

```
grep '|' app/etc/applied.patches.list
```

> The output will look like this:

```
-e 2015-04-14 08:34:22 UTC | SUPEE-5344 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1 | a5c9abcb6a387aabd6b33ebcb79f6b7a97bbde77 | Thu Feb 5 19:14:49 2015 +0200 | v1.14.1.0..HEAD
```

> In this example only SUPEE-5344 has been applied. When you uninstalled a patch, you’ll see this:

```
-e 2015-04-14 15:21:48 UTC | SUPEE-5344 | EE_1.14.1.0 | v1 | a5c9abcb6a387aabd6b33ebcb79f6b7a97bbde77 | Thu Feb 5 19:14:49 2015 +0200 | v1.14.1.0..HEAD | REVERTED
```

Additionally:

1. When compilation is enabled in the backend of your Magento, the Magento patch doesn’t work properly. Disable compilation (navigate to **System > Tools > Compilation** page and click on Disable button) to make sure the patch works. After disabling compilation, check your site with magereport.com again. If the check still comes out as not installed, try re-compiling.
2. Check if the patch is installed in the correct directory;
3. Reload your opcode cache, webserver, php-fpm process and possible other caches. The old code might be still be active;
4. Check your shops’ .htaccess. If you’ve made any adjustements in your .htaccess, it’s possible the patch is only partially installed;

For more details check [here](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-apply-magento-patches/)

Comment: Thank you for that information, I know my store is patch because when I change the admin url to `/admin` 5344 comes back green and as installed but goes back to grey and unknown

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible that http://magereport.com won't recognise some patches.

From their [website](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-apply-magento-patches/):

> **Magereport keeps saying the security patch isn’t installed**
>
> We found out that there are several reasons why patches can come out
>   as uninstalled on Magereport.com, so we recommend you to check the
>   following:
>
> - When compilation is enabled in the backend of your Magento, the Magento patch doesn’t work properly. Disable compilation (navigate to
>     System > Tools > Compilation page and click on Disable button) to make
>     sure the patch works. After disabling compilation, check your site
>     with magereport.com again. If the check still comes out as not
>     installed, try re-compiling.
> - Check if the patch is installed in the correct directory;
> - Reload your opcode cache, webserver, php-fpm process and possible other caches. The old code might be still be active;
> - Check your shops’ .htaccess. If you’ve made any adjustements in your .htaccess, it’s possible the patch is only partially installed;

Comment: Thank you for that information, What I mean is All the patches all installed and showing on magereport but when I change the admin url to something else then it goes back to grey and unknown. And when I change the admin url back to admin then 5344 comes back green and as installed.